# /_ah/queue/deferred strange import error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I have a django 1.5 running on Google App Engine using the `djangoappengine` module for the stitching.
Everything works fine, except that about a half of the calls to /_ah/queue/deferred raise the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../third_party/djangoappengine/deferred/handler.py", line 2, in <module>
    from djangoappengine import main
ImportError: No module named djangoappengine
```

As you can see, the djangoappengine module sits inside the `third_party` directory, and this directory is added to `sys.path` in the `appengine_config.py` file, so there shouldn't be any problems doing `from djangoappengine import main`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'third_party'))
```

The relevant line in `app.yaml` is:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: third_party/djangoappengine/deferred/handler.py
  login: admin
```

What is causing these sporadic import errors? Am I doing something wrong? Maybe there's an import loop I'm not aware of?

Comment: Does it work at all if you remove "third_party/" from the script path in app.yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that my code used old CGI interface instead of the newer WSGI. I Fixed this and the problem didn't return since.

Updated `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application
  login: admin
```

Comment: hello, I am using the same handler as you do and still see that a certain number of tasks don't manage to load all Django environment (in my example it does not see the CACHES env). Anything else you did here?

Answer (score 1):

The deffer library has been known to do some funky things with 3rd party imports. It has something to do with if the deferred task loads a new instance 3rd party libs are slow to get loaded. You have 2 options (with a 3rd I'm not sure will work)

- Use the standard taskqueue call. I can help you re-write if needed.
- If you just need [django](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#django)  and not the special djangoappengine library you should use the app engine one. They are guarantee to be loaded.
- No idea if this will work but may be worth a try is put the import in a try except loop until it gets loaded. Its just an idea never tried doing that myself